# Firebase React Native Functions seemingly not executing

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have been using one machine to develop and recently had to switch over to another. I have been going crazy all day because I thought the code was broken (worked on one machine) but then I realized, for some reason anything firebase related will not run. Such as the example code, just seemingly will not execute at all.

Just fyi I am using react native. I read that firebase just recently started supporting it, so I figured there might be some problems. I did the npm install and all that..

This block just simply auth the user. I have used it before and know it works. But for some reason just simply will not execute.

```
console.log("Start")      
firebaseObject.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(function() {

          console.log("Sign In, Go to login")


        }.bind(this), function(error) {
          // An error happened.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          console.log("ERROR WITH SIGNIN")
          console.log( errorMessage )
        });
console.log("end")
```

if I run this, it will print "Start" and "end" but not run that signInWithEmailandPassword

Comment: I put logging all around it.. and still does not seem to run.. I can't figure out why.. I suspect its something in NPM.. but dosen't seem that way

Comment: I have the latest version installed via NPM

Comment: where do you running it? simulator or device? ios or android?

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same problem for a week...
I have tried running Firebase in redux-thunks as well as in Redux Sagas, besides trying it directly in a component.
Have you had any luck? It seems Firebase itself is working in on itself (I can make refs), but all async calls just hang there forever, no resolve, no errors either.

Comment: I noticied for some reasoning when running the Chrome Debugging firebase goes out, otherwise it works...

Comment: you might also like this guys answer, seems to work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39059931/firebase-sometimes-connecting-sometimes-not-connecting-react-native/39149337#39149337