# Firebase sometimes connecting, sometimes not connecting (React Native)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have a very confusing problem. I have been using Firebase with React Native, which has been working well, but lately sometimes when I start the app it connects, sometimes when I do it does not..

I think it might have to do with the way I connect to the database. I do it in a simple javascript file, that I then call throughout the app on its different views when I want to reference a database. I wasn't really sure how to do this without constantly reinitilizing, so I figured I could do it once and store it in a variable.

Here is the code I use to initialize.. nothing special..exactly what the say to use(obviously removed the key file stuff for the sake of this post):

```
console.log("Global Variable File!")
console.log("This is also where all of our intialization stuff is")

//Connection Stuff
const firebase = require("firebase");


 const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    storageBucket: "",
  };
const firebaseObject = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
console.log("===Firebase Intialized===");
//TODO - Remove me
firebaseObject.database().ref().child('testConnect').push({ title: "Summer2016" });


module.exports = {
  firebaseObject
}
```

I push a object just to verify my connection, sometimes it gets added to the database. Sometimes it dosen't. I also make database references throughout the app. Which sometimes work and sometimes don't

I suspect this is something to do with react native or the way I am trying to use the same object throughout multiple files.. but am not really sure what to do.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I'm encountering the same issue, it seems that the configuration should not be handled at the module level, but instead be executed once the app is ready. You can set the configuration in a method that you manually triggers later on. Since it can be tedious to remember to call this method, I came up with a little wrapper to the `database` ref to automatically init the app the first time we made a call to the `firebase.database()` constructor :

**database.js**

```
import * as Firebase from 'firebase'

let HAS_INITIALIZED = false

const initFirebase = () => {
    if (!HAS_INITIALIZED) {
        const config = {
            apiKey: "**************",
            authDomain: "************",
            databaseURL: "*********",
            storageBucket: "*********",
        }

        Firebase.database.enableLogging(true)
        Firebase.initializeApp(config)
        HAS_INITIALIZED = true
    }
}

export const getDatabase = () => {
    initFirebase()
    return Firebase.database()
}
```

then, in **whatever-file-you-want.js**

```
import { getDatabase } from './database'

getDatabase().ref('...') // etc.
```